# What does "riesce malagevole" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I am studying for the Italian driving test and doing my best to learn new vocabulary as I go along. But I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what "riesce malagevole" means because I'm having trouble finding it used in other contexts. First, here it is in the driving [exam question context](https://www.quizpatenteapp.com/manuale-patente/argomento-teoria/domanda/94990):

> E' obbligatorio ridurre la velocità e all'occorrenza fermarsi quando
> *riesce malagevole* l'incrocio con altri veicoli

My best guess is that this means you are obliged to reduce your speed and even stop when there is an intersection that is difficult to manage involving other cars. But that's a pretty awkward translation.

And here is [another place](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina:Della_Nuova_Istoria.djvu/372) that I found it used, which is just completely beyond me:

> L’imperatrice Eusebia, donna d’illustre prosapia, di splendente
> bellezza, di castità singolare, di colto ingegno, ed elegante, prese
> ad amarlo con tenera costante affezione, la quale se in appresso da
> quella sua pura sorgente traviasse, riesce malagevole alla storia di
> affermare egualmente che di negare.

Comment: I think you got the sense of “malagevole” in the driving text question. What is exactly your question? “Quando riesce malagevole” can be literally translated as “when it turns out to be difficult “

Comment: “*It is compulsory to reduce the speed and, if necessary, to stop when crossing with other vehicles is difficult.*”

Comment: @Hachi This helps too, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation of the first sentence (about the driving exam) is correct.

First, the verb "riuscire" is used to mean "risultare" , "presentarsi" (to appear, to be, to turn out), I take this definition from [Treccani Vocabulary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riuscire/)

> 5. Con un agg. in funzione di compl. predicativo, essere, apparire, risultare

With an adjective as a predicative complement, to be, to appear, to prove to be

Second, about "malagevole" - [From the Treccani Vocabulary, too:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/malagevole/)

> malagévole agg. [comp. di mal- e agevole]. – 1. Non agevole, non
> facile; che presenta ostacoli superabili con fatica:

malagévole adj. [composed by. mal- and agevole] - 1. Not manageable, not easy; that presents obstacles hardly surmountable.

A translation similar to yours could be:

> It is mandatory to reduce the speed and even stop when the intersection between vehicles is proved to be difficult to be managed.

The second sentence is a lot more difficult to be translated because of the pompous and obsolete language; I will try with:

> The Empress Eusebia, a woman of illustrious lineage, of shining beauty, of singular chastity, of cultured intelligence, and elegant, she started to love him with tender constant affection which, if it would have been misled from that pure source, it is difficult to history to affirm as well as to deny.

Basically, the Epress Eusebia (described as a noble, beautiful, pure and intelligent woman) started to become affectionate to a man and if her feelings later had become less pure (misled from the original chaste source), it is very hard to confirm or to negate.

Comment: “*when the intersection between vehicles is proved to be difficult to be managed.*” is not a good translation IMO

Comment: @Hachi yeah maybe you're right... I am unsure about "the crossing between vehicles"... I can't find right now better words

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of malagevole (which I thought was my difficulty) but now I see that riuscire was also a problem for me.  I knew it could mean "to manage to" while malagevole means "not manageable" which is hard to put together.  But it's interesting to me that you take another sense of riuscire for the translation. It's starting to make sense now. Still, examples are the easiest way to learn but I guess this phrase doesn't appear that much.

Comment: Also from Treccani http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riuscire/

"5. Con un agg. in funzione di compl. predicativo, essere, apparire, risultare"

(With an adjective as a predicative complement, to be, to appear, to result)

Comment: Quanto a riesce,  il sinonimo migliore in questo caso mi sembra risulta. La sua traduzione dovrebbe essere prove to be, o, come ha detto Hachi, turn out.

Comment: Your first translation is perfect. It's the original Italian that, while correct, is bureaucratically awkward and has a Middle Ages flavor to it.

Comment: @TonyM I would say that *malagevole* means more "difficult to manage", "not easy to manage", "uncomfortable", "uneasy", and so on, instead of "not manageable".

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is part of the questions for the driving license exam. It has been written by somebody who likes bureaucratic language and the purpose is to puzzle the examinees first about the *meaning* of the question.

It is [question 21003](https://books.google.it/books?id=5lE5DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=obbligatorio%20ridurre%20la%20velocit%C3%A0%20e%20all%27occorrenza%20fermarsi%20quando%20riesce%20malagevole%20l%27incrocio%20con%20altri%20veicoli&source=bl&ots=OQo9gQrhko&sig=ACfU3U2sNTJBKdziVWrEI0LlPyKfYJsj4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip9YjV-cTrAhXN7eAKHcy5AjYQ6AEwCHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=obbligatorio%20ridurre%20la%20velocit%C3%A0%20e%20all%27occorrenza%20fermarsi%20quando%20riesce%20malagevole%20l%27incrocio%20con%20altri%20veicoli&f=false). There is no intersection involved. The situation to imagine is when the road is narrow and two vehicles meet, coming from opposite directions. By the way, the answer is “true”.

The word *malagevole* is a bureaucratism for *difficult*. The prefix *mal* is actually *male* and there are several adjectives so composed: *malcompreso*, *malfatto* and others. However just a few of them are used in common spoken language and *malagevole* is not among them. The prefix *mal* is also used in French and Zamenhof used it for making opposites in Esperanto; which is bad, in my opinion, because both in Italian and in French the prefix mostly has a negative connotation: *la fille malgardée* is not a child that has not been taken care of, but that has been looked after in a bad way.

However *malagevole* and *disagevole* are essentially synonymous and both mean *uneasy*.

*Riuscire* and adjective means something like *to result*. A smooth translation into Italian would be

> È obbligatorio rallentare e, se necessario, fermarsi quando l'incrocio con altri veicoli è difficile.

In English

> It is mandatory to slow down and, if necessary, to stop when it is difficult to pass by other vehicles.

Comment: From this answer I learned not only more about malagevole, but also to consider incrocio more broadly than just 'intersection'. It's also helpful to get insight into the bureaucratic mindset behind some of these questions. At times it seems almost *malevolent*

Comment: @TonyM *Malevolente* is another good example of an adjective that's not the opposite of another: *volente* is somebody who wants to do something (not very common except in fixed phrases), but *malevolente* is somebody who wants to do something bad to others, in thought or in act.

Answer (score 4):

Malagevole combines MAL + AGEVOLE

AGEVOLE comes from AGIO (=ease, comfort)

AGEVOLE (adj.) then means something that can be done easily, with ease, comfortably

MAL+AGEVOLE means that something can NOT be done easily, comfortably

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE and thanks for your answer!