# When does "se" mean "that" versus "if"?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm used to "se" meaning "if" or "whether", but I recently came across cases where "se" can instead be translated "that" in such a way that the meaning can become the exact opposite.

I was trying to understand the answer to this [Italian Driving Theory test question*](http://www.quizeconcorsi.com/wp/showanswer/?qsid=675986):

> Il conducente che può effettuare l'inversione di marcia su una strada
> a doppio senso deve accertarsi **se** la linea di mezzeria è continua.

As shown in the animated gif below, the google sheets translate function translates "se" in this sentence as "if":

> The driver that can perform a U-turn on a two-way street has to make
> sure **if** the centerline is continuous

[image]

By contrast, [google translate App](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#view=home&op=translate&sl=it&tl=en&text=Il%20conducente%20che%20pu%C3%B2%20effettuare%20l%27inversione%20di%20marcia%20su%20una%20strada%20a%20doppio%20senso%20deve%20accertarsi%20se%20la%20linea%20di%20mezzeria%20%C3%A8%20continua) and [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#it/en/Il%20conducente%20che%20pu%C3%B2%20effettuare%20l%27inversione%20di%20marcia%20su%20una%20strada%20a%20doppio%20senso%20deve%20accertarsi%20se%20la%20linea%20di%20mezzeria%20%C3%A8%20continua) translate "se" using "that" for this sentence:

> The driver who can make a U-turn on a two-way road must ensure
> **that** the center line is continuous

In this case, it is sensible to conclude from the "if" translation that the answer to the question is TRUE, while just the opposite conclusion is reached for the "that" translation.

The correct answer, by the way, is FALSE. So you can see it's important for me to learn why "se" is translated by "that" in this case. But I'd like to know a general rule, if there is one.

A [reverso.net search for accertarsi se](https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/accertarsi+se) returns many examples of both "if" and "that" translations, although most are "if/whether".

*For those not familiar with it, the driving test I'm referring to is the test given to all in Italy to obtain the standard driving license. egreg, a regular contributor to this forum, [mentions knowing about it](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/13229/5958). It consists of 40 True/False questions drawn from over 7000 which are widely published on the internet by driving schools, etc... For example, a [google search for the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=deve%20accertarsi%20se&oq=deve%20accertarsi%20se&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60l3.538j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) "deve accertarsi se" turns up mostly websites like that. .

Comment: The second SE must be translated as WHETHER (OR NOT). Ciao!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about this test, its answers, the site quoted or Google Translate, but a sentence saying *X deve accertarsi se Y* undoubtedly means "X must ascertain whether it is the case that Y (or not)". See for instance part 2. of http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se2/ ; you'll see that in none of the described uses, even when the context is ironic or emphatic, *se* can be substituted with *che*.

Comment: It's a true/false question and should be answered *false*.

Comment: @DaG Because of your initial sentence, I added a note to my post to provide more info on the driving test. It seems you are saying the translation for this question should be "if" and not "that" and you even seem to be implying the "that" translation is simply wrong. If you are right, I'm confused by all the "that" translations I found (see my post) and the fact that the accepted answer for this question falls in line with the "that" translation. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DaG I added my comment just for information, because you said you know nothing about the test. But it can actually affect the interpretation. If the text had been “deve accertarsi che la linea di mezzeria sia continua”, the interpretation would be the same (not the meaning, though). Anyway, it's bad Italian nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. Not sure how this affects my answer.

Comment: @TonyM and egreg: I am Italian and have a driving licence. I meant that the test may be misphrased, that that website may be giving a wrong question text or answer, that we don't know about the test's exact meaning (for instance, if "il conducente _può_ effettuare l'inversione", maybe they may ignore the centerline: how knows?), and above all commenting a driving test would be OT here.

Comment: @DaG I'm open to the possibility that this is a "misphrasing" or "wrong answer". So I did my best to check, and I found at least a dozen different sites or pdf documents (some of which looked like legal documents).  In every case I have found the same question phrasing and (where supplied) the same answer. On the other hand, 1 expert is worth more than 1000 internet postings. That's why I come here. Thanks again.

Comment: From a strictly logical viewpoint, if the driver "**può** effettuare" l'inversione, no checking is needed; they already know the centerline isn't continuous. Anyway, that's besides the linguistic point (I may guess that the mistranslations come from the fact that _accertare_ is most often used with _che_, denoting a fact that the writer already assumes is true, while _se_ implies it's dubious).

Comment: @DaG The Treccani reference is difficult (at best) for a beginner like me. Nevertheless, I did my best to understand it, and did as you suggest, substituting 'se' with 'che' for each of the examples. Maybe it's because my understanding is poor, but it seems to me that the substitution does work in some cases there. I can't list them all here, but as examples: "se è vero? Ma è verissimo; se sono contento? Altroché!" My point is that Treccani may be wonderful if you already understand Italian, but its value to someone who doesn't is questionable. Sort of like defining a word with the same word.

Comment: @TonyM: I see your point about Treccani if one's Italian is not already quite good: I mentioned it to substantiate my answer. As for your examples, you can't phrase a question as *_che è vero?_ or *_che sono contento?_ You might use _che_ if, rather than as a (here, rhethorical) question you phrase it as a statement: say, _certo che è vero_ or _ti dico che sono contento_.

Comment: Distinguishing "if" from "that" is key to the original question. I'll use one of the examples: In English "That it is true? But it is the most true!" makes as much sense as "If it is true?  But it is the most true!" In each case the initial phrase makes no sense without context, but in the context of a conversation each makes some sense. Of course the meanings are different, with the "if" version imparting a hypothetical element. Maybe Italian is different. I am marking this as the answer and concluding that original driving question was (at best) poorly worded and (at worst) just plain wrong.